# Xcode 14.1: "Couldn't realize type of self"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, lldb

I recently added `Swift` to my existing `objective-c` static library project and encountering issues when debugging `Swift` code.

When code stops at a breakpoint and I enter a `po` command, such as: `po title`, I get:

> error: expression failed to parse: 
> error: Couldn't realize type of self

Note the following:

1. The project is an `objective-c` static library with recently added `Swift` files.
2. The error appears only when breakpoint is in a `Swift` file. There is no issues while debugging `objective-c` file (*.m file).
3. Xcode version is 14.1
4. Project is using `CocoaPods`.
5. There are no issues with compilation and runtime. The only issue is with debugging.
6. When running `swift-healthcheck` from breakpoint, there are plenty of errors as follow:

> LoadOneModule() -- Missing Swift module or Clang module found for
> "Infra", "imported" via SwiftDWARFImporterDelegate. Hint: Register
> Swift modules with the linker using -add_ast_path.

While `Infra` is the name of my static library.

Any suggestions?